# How to get value from select and put to another select in JSP

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp

I have two select tags with sql query in one jsp page. How to put value from select 1 to the second select?

From

```html
<sql:query var="priv_query">
    SELECT priv_id from en_privilegetypes
    where actual = 1
</sql:query>
```

To

```html
<sql:query var="itemquery">
    SELECT ItemName  from en_items
    where actual = <!-- priv_id  value from priv_query -->
</sql:query>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *JSTL*:

```html
<!-- List of priv_id values -->
<c:set var="priv_id_list" value="" />

<!-- Loop through and append the values to the list -->
<c:forEach items="${priv_query.rows}" var="row">
    <c:set var="priv_id_list" value="${priv_id_list}${row.priv_id}" />
    <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>

<sql:query var="itemquery">
    SELECT ItemName from en_items
    where actual IN (${priv_id_list})
</sql:query>
```

The [`<c:forEach>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/forEach.html) iterates the result set of the first query and append each `priv_id` value to `priv_id_list`.

And then you can use the `IN` clause with `${priv_id_list}` to your second query.

Comment: This works only with 1 value inside select

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This works as i needed but i deleted "${priv_id_list}" inside value in foreach. But when i selected another value inside 'select' tag the second 'select' tag didnt update. Can you help me pls with that issue

Comment: Can you put this code in the question to I understand it better?

Comment: Already did it with JS. Thank you very much for your help!